# Background image opacity increase when adding new div

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity

I am doing my chatbot assignment and I set my background image `opacity` to `0.02`.

However, as I enter more message, the `opacity` increased until `1`.

This is very cool but I never intend to do that.

Just like this:

[image]

How can I stop that?

When the `Send` button is clicked, following code is append into `<div id="chatbox">`:

```
<div class="userDiv"><p class="userText"><span>' + rawText + '</span></p></div>
```

I tried to set the opacity of `<div class="userDiv">` to `0.02` same as the opacity of background image, but then I can't see my message already.

I couldn't find any answer regarding to this issue.

Thank you.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qn7yhrds/9/

Comment: because of this `div::after` .. you defined your background to ALL the divs, so they are stacking above each other and creating this effect. Be more specific and use class instead of tag selector

Comment: I see, then I'll try to change my CSS. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem thanks to [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif)

The problem caused by the code below:

```
div::after {
  content: "";
  background: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/08/07/15/20/newspaper-412452_960_720.jpg");
  opacity: 0.02;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

I defined all the div to have the background image.

So each time I add a new div, a new background image stack over the previous background image, causing the increase of opacity.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvx5dowp/4/